# DocumentSet SendToOfficialFile returns Not Found

Tags: 2013, document-set, records-management

SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, Visual Studio 2013 Premium

I have a requirement to re-open a record that has been moved to a records center. In our case, records consist of a custom DocumentSet based content type and documents within the DocumentSet. When they re-open it, I am to reset the Completion Date to null.

I think the best way to accomplish this is via the `DocumentSet.SendToOfficialFile` method. The following code snippet is from a Console Application I am using for proof of concept.

```
        try
        {

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(recordUrl))
            {

                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {

                    // Parse out some url parameters we will need
                    Hashtable hash = ParseParametersFromUrl(recordUrl);
                    if (!hash.ContainsKey("List"))
                        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Could not parse the ListId from Url '{0}'", recordUrl));

                    // Get the documentset
                    Guid ListId = new Guid(hash["List"].ToString());
                    SPList list = web.Lists[ListId];
                    SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt16(hash["ID"]));
                    DocumentSet docset = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(item.Folder);

                    // Is it a record
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("   Is DocSet Record: {0}", Records.IsRecord(docset.Item)));

                    // Unrecord the files
                    foreach (SPFile f in docset.Folder.Files)
                    {

                        if (Records.IsRecord(f.Item))
                            Records.UndeclareItemAsRecord(f.Item); 

                    } // end foreach file

                    // Null the completion date
                    docset.Item["PICompletionDate"] = null;
                    docset.Item.Update();

                    // Build SPOfficialFileHost
                    string additionalInfo;
                    Uri tgtUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://mywebapp/activesite/_vti_bin/OfficialFile.asmx", docset.ContentType.Name));
                    SPOfficialFileHost targetHost = new SPOfficialFileHost();
                    targetHost.Action = SPOfficialFileAction.Move;
                    targetHost.Explanation = "Move to active";
                    targetHost.OfficialFileName = docset.Item.Title;
                    targetHost.OfficialFileUrl = tgtUri;
                    targetHost.ShowOnSendToMenu = false;

                    // SendTo active edit site
                    OfficialFileResult result = docset.SendToOfficialFile(docset.ContentType.Name, out additionalInfo, targetHost, null, SPOfficialFileSubmissionMode.None);

                    Console.WriteLine("additionalInfo: {0}", additionalInfo);
                    Console.WriteLine("result: {0}", result.ToString());

                } // end using SPWeb

            } // end using SPSite

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            string msg = string.Format("Exception in ReOpen: {0}", ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            return false;

        } // end catch

    } // end Method ReOpen
```

Via the VS Debugger and various `Console.WriteLine()` statements, I can tell you all goes well until the `docset.SendToOfficialFile` line. Even that line executes without an exception, however, `additionalInfo` is empty and result is "Not Found".

Things I have verified:
1) The Content Organizer Settings at the SendTo destination
2) The `OfficialFile.asmx` Url at the SendTo destination
3) DocumentSet and Files are undeclared as records
4) The Completion Date property is updated to null

Things I have tried:
1) Non-null email address in the `docset.SendToOfficialFile` method call
2) Various incarnations of properties on `SPOfficialFileHost` properties
3) Even reversing the direction and **sending to** the records center

Can anyone spot a likely problem? Is there some content organizer configuration I may have missed that is required? Any explanation for the result **Not Found**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course I figured this out not long after posting the question. I saw something in the ULS logs about not finding or not **Assessing** the OfficialFile.asmx so I looked at permissions groups. I noticed a group named "Records Center Web Service Submitters" and I added my user to that group. Re-executed the code posted above and it returned success and completed the move. That's a couple days of my work life I can't get back!